# Cross-client Identity server to client passing access token

Tags: java, spring, authentication, google-oauth, access-token

I am implementing a web application with client and server running on different domains.

I have implemented google based authentication using spring security on server side.

Now, when client calls for login API, server redirects it to google page for authentication. After authentication done, server needs to send `access_token` to client.

As client is sitting on different domain, I am not able to pass `access_token` in header or cookie using `response.sendRedirect(baseUrl)`

Is there any other way to handle token based authentication in such situation.

Comment: That's a really good question.  I have a few links that may or may not help https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth

Comment: Not sure about Google's implementation. Is there an option for redirect URI? If so, the access token will be returned in the address as an argument.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your input, but this link suggests the way to pass token from client to server while I am looking for opposite direction.

Comment: @Eddie Google authentication provides redirection but the cookies are set for server domain as my request is fired from server. Whereas, I want to redirect it to client which is on different domain

Comment: @PoorviNigotiya i know it was my best guess.  The only thing i can think of is your going to have to have your client ask the server there is no way for the server to send it to the client it has no information about your client.

Comment: Your server could provide an endpoint that returns the Access Token. By implementing CORS, your client will be able to access it. However you'll still need to share some form of session/id token to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While scanning through various options I came across two solutions:

1. Link shows how to set cookie from one page to another
   http://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains

   After authenticating successfully on server side it redirects temporarily to a local screen which internally will call client as explained in the above link.
2. Other way is -
   To make login request, client will popup a separate window and pass a secure_id along with request. Also, client stores this secure_id temporarily. 
   Once server completes authentication, it redirects to client page notifying client to close popup window.

   Once popup window is closed, client can request for Access token from server using secure_id which it had stored.